# Extract image URL from RSS Feed using Drupal 7 Feeds Module

Tags: drupal

I am pulling in RSS feeds using the [Drupal 7 feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module and contained in the description field along with the content of the feeds are images. I'd like to extract these on the fly during the import of the RSS feeds so i can use the images native in Drupal. Is there a Feeds sub module which can do this?

I thought [Feeds Tamper](http://drupal.org/node/1246578) might have had a function to do this but i can't see anything related.

I could do this in Yahoo Pipes but I would rather do it directly through Drupal OR another option might be to batch process the nodes after import to get image URL and save it to the Image field.

thanks

Lee

Comment: did you try feeds tamper using your own php?

Comment: ah i didn't know you could add your own PHP through the feeds tamper module. Will check that out. thanks for the tip. Ps i presume this is the module you are referring too? http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper_php

Comment: Ahh, yes sorry, I forgot it was a separate module. It has been a while since I have used it.

Comment: Could you use a HTML parser with Feed Tamper @2pha ? For example. `$html = file_get_html('field_name');
foreach ($html->find('img') as $img) {
    if (preg_match ("\.(jpeg|jpg)$", $img->src) {
        //save $img or $img->src or what's needed?
    }
}`

Comment: I am not sure, I have never used the html parser. I don't see why not though.